# How can I locate an element which was created with Javascript and is not present in the document.body?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an application which plays audios and I am writing some tests for it using Cypress.

The thing is that the audio tags for the audios are created using Javascript, `new Audio()`, and I am having trouble querying these audio tags.

When I add an element, such as an audio tag, using standard HTML, I can find it in the `document.body`.

Now, how can I locate an element, which was created using Javascript, such as `new Audio()`?

Comment: If the newly-created element is not inserted into the DOM, you've to store a reference to the element when you're creating it, otherwise garbage collector will delete it.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements you seek are truly outside of `<body>` (which is possible but not common), then this code can find them

```js
cy.document()
  .find('body')
  .next()        // sibling element to <body> 
  .should('have.text', 'created in javascript script')   // verifies in my example
```

Or use `<html>` as the base element (`<body>` is the default base element)

```js
cy.document()
  .find('html')
  .contains('div', 'created in javascript script')
```

This is the DOM I tested on - the bottom `<div>` is added after `<body>` when the page loads.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>Normal Html element</div>
</body>

<div>created in javascript script</div>

</html>
```